# Is there a way to enable Unicode characters in all browsers on Windows XP?

Tags: html, browser, unicode, utf-8, windows-xp

I'd like to use unicode symbols within my website (especially [Dingbats](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/dingbats.html)).

Is there *any* way to enable this inside all (or at least some) browsers in Windows XP, without having the user to adjust any of his settings?
I use the HTML5 doctype with the charset configured to UTF-8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

The browsers recognize the charset correctly (even IE7). But no special characters are displayed. I only see an empty square box.
This is the case for *all* of the following browsers: IE7, Safari 4, Firefox 3.5, Chrome 4.1, Opera 10.51.

**So, is there any way to configure to enable all (or most) unicode characters for browsers running on Windows XP?**

Comment: This is probably a font issue.

Comment: This is what I found so far. All the tips tell me to enable all the fonts in the Windows XP control panel. I haven't tried that so far.  
I am just curious, if there is a way I can enable it server side. (By setting a charset/codepage f.e.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using graphics instead of Unicode characters. That was the only way I could be sure it looks as expected across all browsers and operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

<'meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'

copy and paste the above meta tag in your head section.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to ask a Microsoft worker mate for a solution. Maybe he know the way... Until the answer will come try `windows-65001` instead of `UTF-8`.

The `windows-65001` is equal to `UTF-8`, but got another name. Maybe it counts for the old systems.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but I think that's kind of overkill for what I'd like to to. Basically, I would like to use Unicode characters/symbols instead of small images.

Comment: épa maybe because you changed your answer completely? ;-)  
Thanks for your efforts. Using `windows-65001` did not solve the problem.